# Customize Select tag on hover

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Quick question. Is there any possible way to customize a select tag?[image]

```
<select className="get-company" name="" id="">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Elige la empresa</option>
   <option value="">Company One</option>
   <option value="">Company Two</option>
</select>
```

For example, I would like to eliminate the arrow and instead make the options appear on hover.

[image]

I would also like to change the way the option box looks right now, but I am not sure how can I select any of those 2 things. I would really appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: are you looking for solution with just html/css? js or other packages? does it have to be a select or would custom component work?

Comment: Hi! I am trying to get a plain html/css solution. However, I would be more than fine with a simple react component

Comment: You cannot use the native browser's  `<select>` for that. it has limitations of what is allowed to be customizable. You would need to use a custom dropdown select component (plenty are available for free on the internet)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/striking-a-balance-between-native-and-custom-select-elements

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/making-a-better-custom-select-element/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-select-like-its-2019/

Comment: Possibly duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895476/104380